# How to install drivers for integrated intel graphics?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, framebuffer, intel-graphics, i915

I am building a minimal Debian system. I installed Debian Wheezy with the netinstall iso, and selected to install only basic system utilities, no desktop environment. The computer that is running this has no graphics card, I just plugged two monitors into the motherboard (MSI's z87g55). Onto that base I installed alsa audio, some programming tools, and xorg.

The problem I am having is the I have no `/dev/fb0`. No framebuffer. I get a tty on one monitor (the smaller one). I tried `# modprobe uvesafb`. This causes the tty to be mirrored on both monitors, though only the bottom half of it is mirrored on the smaller one. This also gives me a framebuffer. Unfortunately, uvesafb doesn't allow me to select the monitor's native resolution. X11 runs fine, I use matchbox-window-manager. It mirrors the display to both monitors.

Googling brought led me to try and add the i915 module, but I get an error:

```
# modprobe i915
ERROR: could not insert 'i915': No such device
```

This is the output with x11 running when I enter it in xterm. In a framebufferless (no uvesafb) tty, it says something cryptic about needing an `intel_agp` module. But it seems I already have`intel_agp`:

```
# modprobe -r intel_agp
FATAL: Module intel_agp is builtin.
```

Is this the right course of action? If so, how can I add the i915 module? If not, what might be a better solution?

If you need more info I'll gladly post it. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, you have a problem with a too old kernel here, because Wheezy is around a year older than your mainboard.

Try a backports kernel and you should be fine.

You can find one here:

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64